# Getting selected li text and setting menu's text with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

1) How do I get the text from the submenu?
 - I can't get the text/value
2) How do I replace the text "Menu" with the clicked submenu's text?
 - When I set the a with a text the caret surprisingly disapear

```
<a id="testa" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul id="testul" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

I have this jQuery to listen for the click:

```
$("#testul").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    var clickedSubMenu = ???;
    $('#testa').text(clickedSubMenu); // <-- removes the caret icon
});
```

Note: It's possible if I use `select` and `option` but because I need the elements to be styles with bootstrap I'm stucked with using

```
<select id="combo">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />
```

---

```
$('#button1').click(function(){ 
    alert($('#combo').val());
});
```

Comment: There's a lot more going on in styled dropdown libraries than just swapping select/option for ul/li. Most hide the select box so it can still be used for accessing the selected field.

Comment: it does as it is supposed to. You can either wrap your `Menu` text in a span and change that span's text on submenu click or just add `text + <span class="caret"></span>` in `testa` html. I think former is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy though,

http://jsfiddle.net/muqjtdg6/

```
$("#testul").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedSubMenu = $(this);
    $('#testa').text(clickedSubMenu.text()); // <-- removes the caret icon
});
```

Note that I used `event.preventDefault()` , you wouldn't need it, but in case you eneter a url for your anchor, your would require to have that statement

**Edit:**

if you want to preserve the caret set the `html()` instead http://jsfiddle.net/muqjtdg6/1/

```
$("#testul").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    console.log(event);

    var clickedSubMenu = $(this);
    $('#testa').html(clickedSubMenu.text()+'<span class="caret"></span>'); // <-- removes the caret icon
});
```

Comment: That would still remove the `.caret` span

Comment: Using `$('#testa').html(clickedSubMenu.text() + '<span class="caret"></span>');` will preserve the caret icon as well.

Comment: ahh I can get it with "text()" I tryed alot with "val()" I thought I tryed with "text()" too.

Comment: Just what I needed. I was so close and yet to far away. Thanks friends. I will accept when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better approach to put link texts and symbols in separate spans. This way it will be easy for styling in case you want to provide separate styling for link texts and link symbols. Also this way you can manipulate only the `text` of the link through javascript.

So html can be

```
<a id="testa" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span class="link-text">Menu</span> 
    <span class="caret">&</span>
</a>
```

And javascript

```
$("#testul").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#testa').find('.link-text').text($(this).text());
});
```